# Quadratic function but with matrix not positive definite.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^TQx-b^Tx$, where $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$, and $Q$ is positive definite. I know that $x_0$ is a unique minimizer for $f$ if and only if $Qx_0 = b$.
However, what if $Q$ is just positive semi-definite? Would $f$ still be quadratic, is $f$ necessarily convex? if not then what other things we can conclude? Does its minimizer $x_0$ still needs to satisfy $Qx_0 = b$?

Comment: If $Q$ is symmetric positive semi-definite, but not strictly positive definite, then $f$ is still convex, and $x_{0}$ will be a minimiser if and only if $\nabla f(x_{0}) = 0 \iff Qx_{0} = b$, but there will either be an infinite number of such minimisers, or no minimiser (i.e. $Qx_{0} = b$ will have either infinitely many solutions, or no solutions, as $Q$ is less than full rank).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Can you please explain further why is $f$ still convex, and why there would be either an infinite number of such minimizers or no minimizers?

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Thanks for the find!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $Q$ is positive semi-definite. Then $f$ is convex because its Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite everywhere ($\nabla^{2}f(x) = Q$ in this case).

Now, since $f$ is convex, $x_{0}$ is a (global) minimiser of $f$ if and only if $\nabla f(x_{0}) = 0 \iff Qx_{0} = b$. If $Q$ is positive semi-definite but is not strictly positive definite, then it is a square matrix with less than full rank, so the linear system $Qx_{0} = b$ has either no solutions or infinitely many solutions (i.e. there are either no minimisers or infinitely many minimisers of $f$).

Comment: Would you mind explaining why it is a square matrix with less than full rank?

Comment: The fact that $Q$ is square is clear. Let's say $Q$ is $n\times n$. If $Q$ is a square matrix that is positive semi-definite but not strictly positive definite, then it must have at least one of its eigenvalues be equal to $0$. This means that it has a (non-zero) eigenvector for eigenvalue $0$, i.e. there exists a $v\ne 0$ such that $Qv=0v=0$. This means that $\mathrm{nullity}(Q) \ge 1$, whence $\mathrm{rank}(Q) \le n-1$ (i.e. $Q$ is less than full rank) by the rank-nullity theorem.